# Ibeacons with codename one

Tags: java, codenameone, ibeacon

i like to know if possible to create a app for ibeacons with codename one ?
I thinks started a test projet for app with codename one and ibeacons.

Thanks for your reply and sorry for my english

bye ;)

Rudy

Comment: You should be sorry, but not for your english. Review [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com//help/how-to-ask) then return to update your question

Comment: @Takarii there are more polite ways in which we can address a new user on the site that don't necessarily put people off...

Comment: ok sorry, i see the how to

Answer (score 0):

We don't have explicit support for the iBeacon protocol but we do support [BluetoothLE](https://github.com/chen-fishbein/bluetoothle-codenameone) which might be used as the basis for portable iBeacon support.

You can also wrap native iBeacon calls using [native interfaces](https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-native-device-functionality-invoke-native-interfaces.html).